Can't declare output in MPLAB X even though I included the header file
I am trying to program a PIC32MX470F512H to execute a simple LED blinking program; however, I am recieving errors when declaring the LED output. I am not exactly sure the reason behind the error, and documentation on it is scarce.

I have looked into cases with similar errors; however, in those, they are still able to successfully compile the code, but I am not.

Reduce your problem to a [mre] and paste the source code of the [mre] into the question as text, not as an image. Paste the compiler error message into the question as text, not as an image. State why you think TRISE4 should have been declared. Is there a header that is supposed to declare it? Did you include the header? Why are you using TRISE4; where did you get that name from?

"I have looked into cases with similar errors..." - that is a recipe for "Cargo Cult programming".  Better to understand how the compiler and preprocessor work, and check the definitions exist and how they are defined yourself  In this context "similar" is seldom helpful - many different problems could have the same symptoms, and there may be relevant symptoms you have not spotted or described here.

The compiler switch -mprocessor=32MX470F512L causes __32MX470F512L__ to be defined, which is used in xc.h to conditionally include proc/p32mx470f512l.h where TRISE4 and RE4 are defined.
However looking at the definition, it is clear that they are defined as members of TRISEbits and PORTEbits respectively. So:
TRISEbits.TRISE4 = 0 ;

and
#define LED (PORTEbits.RE4)


Thank you! Your solution worked; however, the _delay_ms() is classified as an implicit definition, meaning that it is not defined in the header file.

@BrandonHiggs-Carr that is a different question.  Your original question does not mention that and the image of the build output does not show that.  That is why (or just one reason) you should not post pictures of text.  It is likely what the question was down-voted.  You should fix that.

... defining _XTAL_FREQ after xc.h however is an error.  xc.h used _XTAL_FREQ.  It is better defined via a command line -D switch to ensure it is defined before any include for all modules.
